# $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of differential operators, derivations and modules, need help understanding.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, modules, lie-groups

The following was an example given of a module from my lecture notes today.

> Let $A$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of differential operators on $\mathbb{R}$ with $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$-coefficients. We say$$D: C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$$is a **derivation** if it's:
>
> - linear; and
> - satisfies the Leibniz rule, i.e.$$D(fg) = fD(g) + D(f)g.$$
>
> We have$$A = \left\{ \sum_{D \text{ derivation}} f_D(x)D : f_D(x) \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}), \text{ all but finitely many }f_D = 0\right\}.$$Then $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is an $A$-module.

Unfortunately, this was quite confusing, and I could not really follow it. I don't understand the module structure that's going on, and I can't picture it geometrically. Is it possible anybody could help me unpack this by adding some more details? What is the intuition for working with this module?

Comment: It looks like it's claiming $A$ is the set of all $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$-linear combinations of derivations, which is certainly a vector space. But it's not a ring (at least under composition).

Comment: Is the last line supposed to be "Then $A$ is an $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$-module."?